# How to graph the count of multiple responses on the y-axis with age as the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am having issues trying to graph some data. I have a survey question which asks the individual to select up to 3 answers. I want to graph the age on the x-axis with the answer count on the y-axis. This way I am able to see the answers compared to age and see if there is a correlation. However, I can not wrap my head around this and my graphs are coming out wrong.

I first wrangled the data and put it into this dataframe. This is just a snippet as an example.

```
   age answer count
1   86      4     3
2   15     12     1
3   36      8     2
4   10      6     1
5    8      3     5
6   63      6     5
7   77     14     3
8   33     19     5
9   64     16     4
10  84     10     4
```

With it like this I have access to each age that responded with each answer plus the count of responses. So if a single 20 year old responded to this survey with 2 answers then the table would look like this.

```
   age answer count
1   20      2     1
2   20      5     1
```

This issue that comes up is that I don't have a column for all the answers that were left blank so when I go to graph it I end up with a mess.

[image]

I believe if I were able to add all the missing rows it would work but I'm not sure how to do this. Here is a mock-up of what I mean below

```
   age answer count
1   20      1     0
2   20      2     1
1   20      3     0
2   20      4     0
1   20      5     1
```

Any ideas or thoughts on how to proceed from here? My approach might and is probably entirely wrong so any help in pointing me in the right direction would be a life saver.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

With data not grouped by count

```
data = data.frame(age = c(86,15,36), answer = c(4,12,8), count = c(3,1,2))

data_all <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  tmp <- data[i,]%>%expand_grid(1:data$count[i])
  data_all <- rbind(data_all, tmp)
}
data_all%>%
  ggplot(aes(age))+
  geom_density(aes(fill = factor(answer)), alpha = 0.2)

data_all%>%
  ggplot(aes(x))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = factor(y)), position = "identity", alpha = 1, binwidth =1)+
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T)+theme_dark()
```

it will automatically check the number of replicates

another way is to check correlation between age, and number of answer without changing the dataframe would be :

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(age, answer, size = count, colour = answer))+
  geom_point()
```

for ggplot some usefull example are available at https://www.data-to-viz.com/